# jenkins pipeline how to change a stage result base on a % of the test results

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

jenkins pipeline junit use a weird metric for the health of a job,
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/junit/ and if one test fail will mark the stage/job unstable

is it possible to tell the stage  if 20% of the test fail  then mark it as unstable else is sucesfull?

Answer (score 0):

i created a python script that read the result xml, and got the failed test and the totals
and run pytest inside a python script and not from the cli, that way i can control the error code.  since junit addon will mark it unstable if some tests fail since the error code will be other than zero,   so my script

```
pytest_result = pytest.main([my tests, "--junitxml", f"{args.reports_folder}/xml/*name*.xml", "-o", "junit_suite_name=*name*"] )
```

parse the xml with import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET to get the amount of fail  and total amount of tests

```
percentage_fail = (failed_tests/total_tests)*100
```

after i compare it to the threshold

```
if percentage_fail > threshold:
    raise SystemExit(1)
else:
    print("All test working")
    raise SystemExit(0)
```

junit will not let you change the status of the build if become 'UNSTABLE'  the trick is control the error code that comes from running the tests. before passing the report.xml to junit